# Save Arraylist of Objects into Json File

Tags: java, json

I want to save Scores into a JSON File. I wanted to make it like that:
I save my data into a class, which is placed into a ArrayList. So that I can just load my scores from the JSON File when I start my game.

```
package at.htlhl.javafxtetris.externLogic;

public class Scores {

    int gameMode;
    String name;
    String score;

    public Scores(int gameMode, String name, String score){
        this.gameMode = gameMode;
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getGameMode() {
        return gameMode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}

public void writeFile(){

    System.out.println("File wird geschrieben");


    scoreFile = new File(MODEL_FILE_PATH);
    if(!scoreFile.exists()){
        scoreFile.mkdir();
    }


    try {
        JSON_MAPPER.writeValue(scoreFile, scores);
        // or JSON_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(scoreFile, scores);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

But when I try it, I get this

```
invaliddefinitionexception
```

Comment: What is JSON_MAPPER? Out of all the code, the only interesting one for the question seems to be `JSON_MAPPER.writeValue(scoreFile, scores);` but is badly explained.

Comment: where did you define JSON_MAPPER?

Comment: Code is incomplete.  The method `writeFile()` uses three undefined variables: JSON_MAPPER, scorefile, scores.  Please include full stacktrace and indicate where it is being thrown.

Comment: I would suggest you not try any answer posted so far. Please look into a Java JSON API. I think Java offers one, but there are two that are popular. `Jackson`, which I do not like, and `GSON`, which I love. I would suggest researching one of these and using one in your application. There is a chance you will run into pitfalls if you use any answer posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this

```
public class Main {
private final String FILE_PATH = "/tmp/scores.json";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

public Main() {
    toJson();
    fromJson();
}

private void toJson() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Scores scores1 = new Scores(1, "Game-1", "1");
    Scores scores2 = new Scores(2, "Game-2", "2");

    try {
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(new File(FILE_PATH), List.of(scores1, scores2));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void fromJson() {
    try {
        var scores = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File(FILE_PATH), List.class);
        System.out.println(scores);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class Scores {

    private int gameMode;
    private String name;
    private String score;

    public Scores(int gameMode, String name, String score) {
        this.gameMode = gameMode;
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getGameMode() {
        return gameMode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Scores{" +
                "gameMode=" + gameMode +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", score='" + score + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

}